# How to select by id and display in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a brands table in the database. What I want to do is select a few rows by ID and display them in the view.

This is what I have, but I can't get the **Brand.find_by(id: [1,2,3])** to work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

In the brand.rb Model:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base

def selection
    Brand.find_by(id: [1,2,3])
end
```

in the brands/index.html.erb view

```
<% @brand.selection.each do |brand| %>
<%= link_to brand.name, brand %>
<% end %>
```

in the controller

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @brands = Brand.all
end

def show
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @brand = Brand.new
end

def create
  @brand = Brand.new(review_params)
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using the .find method and pass it the array:

```
array_of_ids = [1,2,3]
Brand.find(array_of_ids)
```

Then could you dump the results of @brand.selection so we can see what you are getting back.

Also may I ask, I don't know the specifics of why you are doing this but, would it not make more sense to allow your selection method to accept the array as an argument and pass it to the find method rather than hard coding it.

```
def selection(array_of_ids)
    Brand.find(array_of_ids)
end
```

Also, in terms of trying to keep as much logic out of the views, perhaps you should set a variable in the controller that calls the `.selection` and then pass that to your view.

```
def index
    @brands = Brand.all
    @selected_brands = Brand.selection
end
```

Furthermore, unless Brand.selection is something you are going to re-use somewhere else (If you are, great), you might just stick it directly in the controller when declaring the variable:

```
def index
    @brands = Brand.all
    array_of_ids = [1,2,3]
    @selected_brands = Brand.find(array_of_ids)
end
```

In your views then just use:

```
@selected_brands.each do |brand|
  //something
end
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me. I thought of sticking it in the controller but couldn't quite nail the code I needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.